# Qliksense Enterprise Authentication and connection to React via enigma js and ticket api

Tags: authentication, qliksense

Currently trying to set up a connection to qlik sense to pull mash ups into a react app.

When trying to access the app, the users are redirected to internal windows authentication when they get 'notification: OnAuthenticationInformaiton' and mustAuthenticate: true.

After a successful login the user is redirected back to localhost app with the qlik ticket and mustAuthenticate should be false. However in our case mustAuthenticate is still true.

Has anyone had that issue in the past/has any tips on how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the ticket you'll have to open the connection again and pass the ticket in the web socket session url:

> https://my-host/app/engineData-or-appId?qlikTicket=**ticket-goes-here**

```js
const session = enigma.create({
    schema,
    url: `https://my-host/app/engineData-or-appId?qlikTicket=ticket-goes-here`,
    ...
```

Code example can be found [here](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/blob/8b23d6dd1bf0053e6f4f9a1b332f7be7ff94342d/examples/authentication/sense-using-ticket/ticket.js#L15)

Just to mention couple of things about tickets:

- tickets are short lived (think its 1 min). If they are not consumed in this timeframe they are deleted and cant be used
- tickets are deleted once they are consumed (aka one ticket can be used only one time)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been going through cookie log and it seems like the X-Qlik-Session cookie and ticket info disappear as soon as the user lands on the react app page. Would you happen why that could happen?

Comment: for the session cookie ... check if the SameSite attribute is set to `none` https://community.qlik.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Missing-SameSite-attribute-blocks-requests-in-Chrome-80-and/ta-p/1712551

Comment: for the ticket. not quite sure. the ticket is something temporary. so techincally you should not see the same ticket again. it might be something with the react app as well? In my workflows the web app is open without ticket in the url. once the user is re-reiceted back from QS then the ticket is in the url. but if you refresh (or make change in the code and the page is refreshed) then the ticket should not be in the url anymore. or if its still there (and it was already consumed) you will be denited access (or depends on your logic will be re-directed to qlik for authentication)

Comment: right, we should still have X-Qlik-Session cookie though when using react app to access mashups/API correct?

Comment: yes. once authenticated qlik will send the x-qlik-session cookie to the browser. but you will see it in the mashup only if the SameSite attribute allows it. If not then the cookie will be visible only on qlik page (like the Hub)